# Are the Infinities in QFT Perturbation (closed loop diagrams) a Consequence of Point Interactions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, singularities, interactions

I have heard (and read) that the infinities that arise in QFT interactions using higher-order perturbations are "a problem that comes down to the fact that the interactions occur at a single space-time point."

But I've never found or heard an elaboration or explanation of this assertion, and I don't understand why this would be so.

Can anyone elaborate on this and explain it for me (as well as why interaction calculations that would be "spread out" might avoid these infinities), and offer some good references on this specific subject?

Comment: Note this [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600512/), but I would not recommend the one answer that it has.

Comment: Just as a note: renormalisation is not only connected with QFT, it is also required in quantum mechanics when dealing, for example, with system with point interactions.